# how to send data to controller ruby by ajax

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

In application.js :

```
function get_cell_id(select_id)
{
  $.ajax({
      url: "/assign_variable",

      type: "GET",
       data:{channel:"abc"},
      error: function(){     
      alert('fail')
      }
  });
}
```

in static_pages_controller

```
def assign_variable
  @Four_Season_Set_Channel= params[:channel]
  end
```

in routes.rb

```
 match '/assign_variable', to:'static_pages#assign_variable', via: 'Get'
```

but i got alert fail, please help me fix it.

Comment: Which Rails version are you using?

Comment: Check your console for what error is happening at the rails end ...

Comment: it said : 500 internal server error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to be rendering something, be it HTML/plain-text. That should solve the problem. Else you would be getting a 204 error (NO CONTENT). Also, in the javascript-error-function, try alert/log the error-code. That will help too.

Comment: tks, can you tell me how can I display @Four_Season_Set_Channel in view ?

Comment: Honestly,that's a bad question. I have no clue on that the @Four... is all about, neither the requirement. From what I see, you are sending across a hard-coded value "abc" to the server. And in the controller, what do you intent to do?

Comment: I send data from js and want to assign it to ruby-variable, finally, i want to show it to sure that data is assigned.

Comment: OK. Looks like you are simply playing-around/learning. In the controller, use the code in https://gist.github.com/satyatechsavy/7637946#file-stackoverflow-help . Also, in the JS, add one more parameter "dataType" and the value to "script".

This means, your ajax request is expecting a Javascript as a response. And in the controller, you are sending a JS-response to ALERT the value.

Comment: I did what you say and "page.alert @Four_Season_Set_Channel " doesn't work.

Comment: Processing by StaticPagesController#assign_variable as */*
  Parameters: {"channel"=>"abc"}
  Rendered static_pages/home.html.erb (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 7ms (Views: 7.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
[2013-11-25 15:18:49] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body.
 Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true

it 's my console logs, i want to use  @Four_Season_Set_Channel as variable to make somethign such as if(@Four_Season_Set_Channel ).... but it's seem not work al all.